# My Android OpenGL app on Android is user lower resolution than supported

Tags: android, opengl-es, screen-resolution

I'm using a Motorola Defy which has a 480x854 pixel resolution in which I'm testing an OpenGL ES application, but I can't get my OpenGL surface to run on my phone's full resolution.

I read other questions on it and I have already setup my manifest like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="com.test.game.MyApplication">
    <activity android:name="com.test.game.VikingsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:resizeable="true"/>
</application>
```

But it still won't work. What am I missing?

Comment: When you say your app runs at a "lower resolution", are you seeing abnormally large pixels? Or is your scene occupying a lesser region of the screen (resulting in black borders)?

Comment: I mean larger pixels when I run it in the device and lesser region on the emulator's screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: At the moment it looks like you've got "NoTitleBar" specified, not "NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: You are right. I've added the .Fullscreen and it didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it for my app: Add

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

before your `<application>` tag.